# What do I use to catalogue miscellaneous things (apart from music, films and books)?

Tags: cataloging

There are many programs to help catalogue music, video and books but I could not find anything that could build a catalogue of misc items (pretty much anything - I want to be able to define the catalogue tree and items attributes as I roll on).

I guess what I need is more like an ORM with simple GUI to configure/enter your data. Can't believe there is nothing out there and I'll have to write the thing myself.

Windows/Linux or web-based (as long as can be hosted locally) will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GC Star](http://www.gcstar.org/) sounds close to what you are looking for.

Comment: yeh, this is more or less something close, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What the cataloguing software for e.g. books does, is to give you a more or less nice GUI to a database built with a schema which contains columns for the usual properties of a book. If you want a cataloguing tool for everything, you want a GUI to a database which can hold columns for any type of thing.

Sounds exactly like Access to me.